# Adding NumPy array to existing HDF5 file in PyTables?

Tags: numpy, hdf5, pytables

I have two sliced Numpy arrays stored in memory, say a and b, shape 1*480*640, how can I add them to an existing HDF5 file in PyTables? The existing HDF5 file has three arrays: n1,n2,n3, I want the new HDF5 file to have 5 arrays: n1,n2,n3,a,b . Thx!

Comment: What did you try? Did you try the function `createArray`?

Comment: How did you get the other arrays into the HDF5 file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [createArray](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html#file-methods-hierarchy-manipulation) on the file object to do that (or if you need compression use `createCArray`/`createEArray`):

```
File.createArray('/','a', numpyArray)
```